# GLFW Linker Command Failed (Exit Code 1) When Building with VSCode MACOS

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, linker, glfw

After getting up and running with the C++/C extensions of Visual Studio Code, I am attempting to use GLFW to create a window. I have downloaded GLFW, and the file structure of my project is as follows:

Engine (Workspace Folder) -> Source Files -> test.cpp

Engine (Workspace Folder) -> Dependencies -> GLFW Libraries

Here is my C++ code to generate the window:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        // Window or OpenGL context creation failed
    }
}
```

Here is my tasks.json config for building with clang++:

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/Users/mynamew/Desktop/Engine/Dependencies/glfw-3.3.4.bin.MACOS/include"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
```

And here is my c_cpp_properties.json config:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/Users/myname/Desktop/Engine/Dependencies/glfw-3.3.4.bin.MACOS/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

When I attempt to build the project, I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in test-9301bf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Is there a compatibility issue between my Mac architecture and GLFW thats causing a linking issue? If so, is there any fix or am I just out of luck? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, a bit of a meta question but does the linker error indicate that compilation was successful but only the linking failed? As I understand it the linker comes after compilation.

Comment: You did not link the glfw library in the args of your `tasks.json` related: [https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html)

Comment: @drescherjm When I link the library as follows:                 "-L/Users/tyler/Desktop/Engine/Engine/Source Files/Dependencies/glfw-3.3.4.bin.MACOS/lib-x86_64",
                "-lglfw3" I still get the same error message unfortunately.